# Using Proxy to attaching callback to object with self-setting method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scope, reactive-programming, es6-proxy

I'm looking to create a proxy on an object (the `Counter` instance below) which, when changed, will result in all functions of the `callbacks` array being triggered (the `callbacks` array will be populated with `() => this.setState()` from any React component using data from the counter instance... this way, a re-render will be triggered and reflect the new data). One constraint is that the object is only manipulated from within itself (instance methods `increment` and `decrement`). Another constraint is that the `callbacks` array needs to be editable even after the object and proxy are initialized (and then triggered whenever the instance methods are called). I'm trying to use this technique to re-render a React Component based on the activity of the counter class. Here's my current attempt to do so (doesn't re-render when incrementing or decrementing). Thank you so much for taking the time to read this over and I really appreciate any advice or suggestions!

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class Counter {

  count = 0

  increment = () => this.count++

  decrement = () => this.count--

}

const counter = new Counter()

const callbacks = []

const validator = {

  // recursively creates callback for any object change...
  // not only for top-level properties

  get(target, key) {
    return (
      typeof target[key] === 'object' &&
      target[key] !== null
    )
      ? new Proxy(target[key], validator)
      : target[key]
  },

  set() {
    callbacks.forEach((update) => update())
    return true
  },

}

const proxy = new Proxy({}, validator)

Object.assign(proxy, counter)

class CounterComponent extends Component {

  counter = {}

  constructor() {
    super()
    this.counter = counter
    callbacks.push(() => {
      this.setState({})
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button
          children='-'
          onClick={ this.counter.decrement }
        />
        <span children={ this.counter.state.count } />
        <button
          children='+'
          onClick={ this.counter.increment }
        />
      </div>
    )
  }

}
```

Comment: FYI, proxies are slow. If you intend to use it in production and not just as a proof of concept, you may be unsatisfied with overall performance. As for `Counter`, I don't see why a proxy is needed. There's a fixed amount of properties, they could make use of descriptors.

Comment: @estus thanks for the feedback on the question. Yea, it's more of a proof of concept. As for why a proxy is needed, I suppose it might not be if I understand your suggestion correctly: could I attach a callback to the getter descriptor of the Counter instance?

Comment: I'm not yet totally sure how the whole thing should work, so I can't come up with an answer. But as a rule of thumb, when a list of accessed properties is known (`Counter` members), a proxy can be replaced with a set of descriptors. And class getters and setters are very fast.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks for your help. I see now that the best solution doesn't involve proxying :)